# Is there any method to extract transactions for an bitcoin address which is not in my wallet using bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I have setup Bitcoin core and trying build an API to fetch all transactions under an address ( not in my wallet ).

[Bitcoin core RPC documention](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/wallet/importaddress/) says that an address which is not in my wallet needs to be imported. So I did the same using `importaddress` while setting rescan true e.g. `importaddress '35z3Re9SgLHBfeg7y1HdR35t9HrTqTsKFV' 'test' true`. It took more than a week to rescan the whole blockchain database.

After importing the address, when I issued the [`getaddressinfo`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/wallet/getaddressinfo/) RPC command I got empty set of transactions in response.

Am I missing something ? Can you please help me here with the steps ?

Comment: `getaddressinfo` doesn't return transaction information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `scantxoutset` command to scan for unspent outputs for a given address (or script).

Importing an address adds it to your wallet, and you will see transactions for imported addresses under the `listreceivedbyaddress` and `listtransactions` commands.